# This question is wrongly titled and the body has to be recast in sectarian terms

Tags: discussion

[Death of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/death-of-lord-shiva?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Death of Lord Shiva?

is a shocking, hurtful title.

> Is Lord Shiva dead? Where is he? Is he still in Shiva Avatar or has engaged in a new Avatar for Kaliyuga?

Shiva is a moola form (although some scriptures say he is born of other deities) and the question of his dying is blasphemous.

The question should be recast as "are there some sects that believe" followed by the questions stated in the body.

Comment: Why hurtful? OP doesn't seem to have bad intention about Shiva.

Comment: Siva is actively worshiped by hundreds of millions TODAY.  Although HSE is visited only by a few thousands, we need to post things here as if all practicing Hindus are watching.  It is one thing to ask if one or the other limiting event happened to a deity in scripture (birth, outcome of battles etc.) but quite another to ask if a member of the Trimurti is dead (in the present tense).